# Polynomial rings and quotients of homogeneous ideals

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials, quotient-group

I fear that this is a stupid question, but I want to have a go anyway.

Let $k$ be a field, and let $f(x,y)$ be an irreducible homogeneous quadratic polynomial in $k[x,y]$.

*Question*: (when) is $k[x,y]/(f(x,y)) \cong (k[x]/f(x,1))[y]$ ?

Probably I am seeing ghosts, but is there some more general (correct) identity that I am totally missing ? Can the assumptions on $f(x,y)$ be relaxed ?

Comment: Can you give an example when this isomorphism is true? For instance, if I take $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$ over $ℂ$, then it is not true since $f(x,1) = x^2$ is reducible (when one ring is an integral domain, any isomorphic ring is too). If you want the isomorphism to be over $k[x,y]$, we need $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,1)$ to be associated, it is very restrictive: it means that $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial of $x$ only. By the way, there is no quotient group here, so this tag should be removed.

Comment: @Idéophage : $f(x,y)$ is not homogeneous in your example ?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. [edited comment to remove uninteresting last part]

Answer (score 0):

In characteristic not $2$, when ${b^2-4c}$ is not a square of $k$ (which is impliçed by the irreducibility) then  $$k[x,y]/(x^2+byx+cy^2) \cong k[y,\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}y]$$ Which is a subring of the polynomial ring $$k[\sqrt{b^2-4c}][y]$$ 
As the former doesn't contain $\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}$.

$k[y,\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}y]$,$k[\sqrt{b^2-4c}][y]$ are two integral domains and they have the same fraction field $k[\sqrt{b^2-4c}](y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \in k[x,y]$ be a homogeneous polynomial. There is a natural injective map
$$
k[x,y]/(f(x,y)) \hookrightarrow (k[u]/f(u,1))[v] : x \mapsto uv, y \mapsto v.
$$
However, if $\deg f > 1$, then $u$ is visibly not in the image of this map.

Note that $A := k[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ has a grading induced by the usual grading on $k[x,y]$ since $f$ is homogeneous. Hence if an element of $A$ satisfies a polynomial equation over
$k$, then it must be an element of degree $0$, i.e. already in $k$. In particular
the equation $f(T,1) = 0$ has no root in $A$ if $f$ is irreducible over $k$ but it
does have a root (namely $u$) in $(k[u]/f(u,1))[v]$. In conclusion if $f$ is irreducible and homogeneous of degree $> 1$, then $k[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ is not isomorphic to 
$(k[u]/f(u,1))[v]$.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why there isn't any isomorphism ? (I do not see immediately why that follows from your other observations.) Thanks.

Comment: The point is that A is a graded ring and has no elements of negative degree. If $u \in A^\times$ is a unit, then it must be of degree 0 since otherwise $u^{-1}$ has components of negative degree. The degree 0 part of $A$ is the field $k$. On the other hand, the other ring contains a proper finite extension of $k$. Thus they cannot be isomorphic. Does that help?